# Effect of training on air intake

Tags: oxygen

Say we have two men, A and B, A is trained and B is not. Apart from that they have the same weight and running technique. When they both run at the same speed for 5 km does the amount of air they inhale differ?

As they both need the same amount of energy for the excercise I would think that they need the same amount of oxygen for the chemical processes in the muscles. I found studies that show that the heart rate decreases but I am not sure if this directly shows that they need less air because it could be that they can transport more oxygen per heart beat.

Comment: You're asking if physical fitness matters. Yes, it does.

Comment: You know of any good study about this?

Comment: Your question is so broad that probably hundreds of studies address it in some way. Any basic exercise physiology textbook will answer this.

Comment: For example? I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found something:

Andrew, George M., Carole A. Guzman, and Margaret R. Becklake. "Effect of athletic training on exercise cardiac output." Journal of Applied Physiology 21.2 (1966): 603-608.

Porszasz, Janos, et al. "Exercise training decreases ventilatory requirements and exercise-induced hyperinflation at submaximal intensities in patients with COPD." CHEST Journal 128.4 (2005): 2025-2034.